# Mock a raw_input python

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I have this function that should receive a list [x,y]

```
def input_origem():
    origem = raw_input("Entre com o valor de x: ")
    origem = eval(origem)
    return origem
def input_saida():
    destino = raw_input("Entre com o valor de y  ")
    destino = eval(destino)
    return destino


def my func(origem, destino):

..
...
code 
..
...

print  myfunc(input_origem(), input_saida())
```

This code works well, but I don't know how to mock this function.

I tried this way:

```
class TEste(base.TestCase):
    @base.TestCase.mock.patch('mypath.input_origem')
    @base.TestCase.mock.patch('mypath.input_saida')
    def test_movimento_cavalo(self, origem_mock, saida_mock):
        origem_mock = self.mock.MagicMock()
        saida_mock = self.mock.MagickMock()
        myfunc(origem_mock, saida_mock)
        myfunc.should.be.equal([1,1])
```

But the test never completes. When I cancel, I get:

> origem = raw_input("Entre com o valor de x: ") 
>   KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to mock `__builtin__.raw_input` using whatever facilities you normally use to mock things.

A very simple example using `unittest` and `mock` looks like this:

```
import unittest
import mock
import __builtin__

def test_raw_input():
    return raw_input()

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(__builtin__, 'raw_input')
    def test_stuff(self, mock_raw_input):
        mock_raw_input.return_value = 7
        self.assertEqual(test_raw_input(), 7)

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of this?

Comment: @PythonMaster -- Added a simple example.